# Javascript Async promise: cannot get my data

Tags: javascript, async-await

I'm trying to apply a function to map each element that my promise return after a fetch request.
Somehow I can log the result to the console but I cannot use it further more.
Here is my code:

```
async function init() {
  const res = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`);
  const data = await res.json();
  console.log(data);
  function getUsersNames (data){
      data.map((user, index)=>{
          console.log(user[index].name);
      })
  }
}


init();
```

and this is a screenshot of my output in the console:
[image]

Any help would be great! Thanks

Comment: why did you create getUsersNames method? just call data.map...

Comment: If you're not interested in the return value of `.map()` then you shouldn't be using `.map()`

Comment: `getUsersNames` is never called. Where and how do you execute it?

Comment: put return data in your init() function. delete inside this function getUsersNames. call init().then((data)=>{ ... .whatever you want.... })

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is at line 7, you are calling `user[index].name` but it should be `user.name`. In the map function you are already looping through your array.

Comment: ...or `data[index].name` (but this is just for completeness^^)